# How does the JLS grammar match simple field accesses (obj.f)?

Tags: java, java-8, language-lawyer, grammar, jls

I was looking at the [JLS Chapter 19 grammar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-19.html) trying to figure out how a simple field access is parsed:

```
obj.field
```

It looks to me like the first variant of the *FieldAccess* production is probably involved

> *FieldAccess*:
>
>   *Primary*
>   `.`
>   *Identifier*
>   `super`
>   `.`
>   *Identifier*
>   *TypeName*
>   `.`
>   `super`
>   `.`
>   *Identifier*

and that *Primary* should then be involved in parsing the `obj` part.  *Primary* doesn't seem to be involved with parsing a simple reference like *ExpressionName*.   That seems to be reached via *PostfixExpression*.

> *PostfixExpression*:
>
>   *Primary*
>   *ExpressionName*
>   *PostIncrementExpression*
>   *PostDecrementExpression*

and, AFAICT, *PostfixExpression* is not left-recursive with *Primary*.

Am I missing something?

Is there some other way that a *Primary* bottoms out on an *ExpressionName* or *AmbiguousName*?

---

EDIT:

I made a [DOT→SVG graph](http://svgur.com/s/ER) of the relationships between non-terminals in the grammar.  If an edge is blue then there is a left-recursive use by the non-terminal at the start of the non-terminal that follows the head of the arrow.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8)?

Comment: @Tunaki, No.  That's linked from chapter 19.

Comment: Well, this is what a Primary is. The chapter 19 also links to it.

Comment: @Tunaki, If you're talking about the "This part of the grammar of the Java programming language is unusual, in two ways. ..." part, then that's relevant.  But AFAICT that doesn't actually address the problem.  It seems that the "names are grouped together with primary expressions a little later"  doesn't solve the problem because *PostfixExpression* isn't reachable from *Primary* without parentheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as you already noted, `obj` is not a *Primary*, hence, the production *Primary*`.`*Identifier* does not apply to `obj.field`. Since no `super` key is involved, the other alternatives don’t apply either, so the entire *FieldAccess* does not apply.

This is nothing to worry, as this is only a named grammar rule, not a necessary requirement for letting Java source code access a field.

As you also noted, *PostfixExpression* includes *Primary*, but not only that, it also includes *ExpressionName*:

```
ExpressionName:
    Identifier 
    AmbiguousName . Identifier

AmbiguousName:
    Identifier 
    AmbiguousName . Identifier
```

So `obj.field` matches *ExpressionName*, thus, matches *PostfixExpression*. Now, there is a long chain of productions from *Expression* to *PostfixExpression*, incorporating the entire operator precedence rules, but simply said, a *PostfixExpression* is allowed everywhere, where an *Expression* is allowed.

There’s one notable divergence, *assignments*:

```
Assignment:
    LeftHandSide AssignmentOperator Expression

LeftHandSide:
    ExpressionName 
    FieldAccess 
    ArrayAccess
```

Assignments are expressions, so they may also appear on the right-hand side of an assignment, however, the left-hand side is special. There, we see *FieldAccess*, to which `obj.field` (unintuitively) not belongs, as well as *ExpressionName*, which `obj.field` matches.

---

Maybe it helps to keep in mind, that when `obj.field` is parsed, the parser doesn’t know that it is a field access. It might also be the case that `obj` is a package and `field` is a class name or that `obj` is a class name and `field` is an inner class name. It is the surrounding context that will require it to be resolved to  field (and it still could be a `static` field in a class `obj`).

The *FieldAccess* production lists those cases that unambiguously are a field access, recognizable at parsing time, without looking at its surrounding context.

Comment: Ok.  The "`obj.field` matches *ExpressionName*" makes sense so my mistaken assumption was that *Primary* is involved.  That's what I was missing.  It seems intuitive to me that `foo.bar.baz;` is unambiguously a field access even though `foo.bar` is ambiguous.

Comment: No, `foo.bar.baz;` is either, ambiguous or not a valid construct at all, as it’s not a statement. However, if it is preceded by `import`, it is a valid construct `import foo.bar.baz;`, but not a field access. It would be a field access when preceded by, e.g. `x=`: `x=foo.bar.baz;`. Examples for unambiguous field accesses are `this.field` or `foo().bar`…

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  My example was broken because field accesses aren't allowed as top level expression statements.  I meant that in `(foo.bar.baz)` when parsing starts from *Expression*, `baz` in unambiguously the name of a field, but it is ambiguous whether `foo.bar` refers to a class (the whole compiles to a *getstatic* instruction), or is itself an expression (the whole compiles to a *getfield* instruction).

Comment: The problem is, when encountering `foo.bar.baz` during parsing, you don’t know its meaning right at this point, i.e. even if we are in an expression context, we have to know what follows `foo.bar.baz`, e.g. a subsequent `.anotherName` could make it ambiguous, but if followed by `.class`, it would be unambiguously not a field access. A subsequent `+` or `=` would be a different picture.

Comment: I interpreted "ambiguous" to mean "there is more than one path through the grammar that ends up popping the start production and consumes the whole input."  If by "ambiguous" you meant "the amount of lookahead needed to commit to a variant is unbounded" then I think we largely agree.